# how to apply date range filter to get sum total

Tags: php, mysql

Iam new to php & mysql. I got two columns, team & Date in mysql database.
I am tried the code to find total based on Date filter.(i.e. 6-Aug-2013)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Date, SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, SUM(workloss) AS Balance FROM `worksheet` GROUP BY Date")
or die(mysql_error());
```

I get the total, But also I get 10-Aug-2013 total below that. I dont need that. Any suggestions pls??

Comment: You can use where i.e SELECT Date, SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, SUM(workloss) AS Balance FROM worksheet Where Datefield between '2013-08-10' AND '2013-08-10'

Comment: Or just a WHERE Date = '2013-08-10'

Comment: iam using search filter. so if i search on different dates, 'where' will not get correct output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filter = "2013-08-10";

$sql = "SELECT Date, 
                SUM(issuedwt)  AS IssuedTotal, 
                SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, 
                SUM(workloss)  AS Balance 
       FROM `worksheet` 
       WHERE Date = '".$filter."' 
       GROUP BY Date";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: i get total for that particular date 2013-08-10.(i.e. for 2013-08-10 date, total = 10) If i search for another date,  (2013-08-06 date, it shows 10 again, but total should be 15. )

Comment: Show what you have done to implement this that gives you the wrong date.

Comment: Ungh. The SQL query needs to be in a string, and the `$filter` assignment lacks a terminating semicolon.

Comment: Thx Sverri. Edited the typing mistakes (Should really be typing in a code editor, rather than in the SO form

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `date` field from `select` clause. Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, SUM(workloss) AS Balance FROM `worksheet` GROUP BY Date")
or die(mysql_error());
```